# pointing to use a different assembly for specific application c# forms/mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I using new Amazon SDK that uses their latest dll. I can't replace the existing (old) referenced assembly/dll because some the old applications are based on it and most its functions are already depreciated. My colleagues never updated their applications. My problem applies to all other applications not just the one's that uses amazon but oracle,ajaxtoolkit,EF, so on and so forth. I always develop my application with the latest assemblies and every time I pushed it to production some applications would fail. I'll be lucky if redirecting it to a newer version can make it work but most of the time I have to recode and use the old assembly which I am not a fan of. Is there a way that I can point my application to use different dll or bin location? I am seeing some codebase config in web.config but I'm not sure about it.

I really need this..Every time I tell them to update their application and library they always complain..I can't do anything they are my seniors here.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try `bindingredirect` in web.config, although this works when you have multiple versions of same assembly. Not sure if it can help in your case.

See various examples here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That is what I'm using..But I'm not sure if a depreciated function will work if I use that.. As for the AWSSDK I just figured out that the new sdk uses a different assembly name, so my new application will still work without affecting the old ones.However I still need to know the answer or the way how to, for other updated libraries.

Comment: Are you trying ask that for the same project you want to use both old and new library?